# AWS Lambda SES and Email destination

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have my AWS IoT button configured and my Lambda function created, been through the process and configured in us-east-1 using email env variable = foo@domain.com and worked as expected.  I then attempted to adjust the email env variable to a diff email, foobar@domain.com but emails are still going to the original address.  I reset and everything (at least what I think is everything, deleted lambda function and deleted IoT thing, security, rules) and and started over, with same result, emails are still going to foo@domain.com

I thought maybe it was an issue with reading the env variable so I modified "const EMAIL = process.env.email;" to be "const EMAIL = 'foobar@domain.com';", still no luck.

Thoughts?  I am sure I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

The issue was not in the lambda function is was the SNS topic which only had the one email confirmed.  Every time I updated the email env variable is added the email to the SNS topic and requested confirmation, the target email address was blocking the confirmation email because it was an unknown sender.  Wasn't until I looked at the SNS topic, which I should have done sooner that the light bulb went off.